# VS Code Salesforce extensions not activating

Tags: vs-code, ide

I've been using VS Code for a few years now, and in different computers and even in a couple of companies but a several weeks ago I have been having this issue. When opening or running any command in the command prompt from the SFDX library in VS Code (like "SFDX: Authorize an Org") I see the activating extensions in the bottom of the window like shown in the image:

[image]

And after a few seconds it disappears and nothing happens, no error and no result. I can however run commands from the terminal using the sf and sfdx libraries. Any idea of why this is happening, or where I can checks logs? I've found nothing in the VS Code Log files.

I have reinstalled all components(VSCode, SF CLI, SF Extension Pack), and this even solved the problem a few weeks ago but it keeps coming back. Now reinstalling no longer solves the problem.

Edit: After updating the Salesforce CLI, nothing changed. Checked the running extensions tab and these 3 are stuck in activating:

[image]

Comment: update your cli and restart your vscode see if that does the trick?

Comment: Had some updates to do but was no help. Updated the description with the running extensions tab from the command "Developer: Show Running Extensions". Seems that the Apex, Salesforce CLI and SOQL extensions are stuck.

Comment: i did run into this issue earlier this year, i reinstalled salesforce extensionpack for vscode. that worked for me. if you can give it a try.